# How to parse a clojure expression?

Tags: programming, parsing, lisp, string-manipulation

[Clojure](https://clojure.org/) is a lisp-like language that runs on JVM and in Javascript. I just started learning it and I'm building a simple parser with Mathematica to understand and visualize it.

Like other lisps every Clojure expression is really a tree in polish notation, and so has a simple normal form that looks like this: `(head expr expr ...)` where expr is a symbol, string, or other atomic type.

Ok, so here's an example of my function parseTree at work:

```
s = "(defn double-int [i] (* i 2))";
c = parseTree[s]
TreeForm@c
```

[image]

Unfortunately, my function uses string patterns in a way that seems very brittle to me - I couldn't think of a better way to do it, but I was hoping you all might.

```
parseTree[s_String] := Module[{lst=Characters@s,rules={},srules={},p,a,n,l,ph,res},
    p=Cases[Thread[{lst,Range@Length@lst}],{"("|")",_}]//.{h___,{"(",i_},{")",j_},t___}:>{h,t,{i,j}};
    a=StringTake[s,#]&/@p;
    n=a[[1]];
    Do[
        l=parseLeaf[n];
        ph="$"<>ToString@Hash[l];
        AppendTo[rules,ph->l];
        AppendTo[srules,a[[i]]->ph];
        n=StringReplace[a[[i+1]],srules];
        ,{i,1,Length[a]-1}];
    res=parseLeaf[n]//.rules;
    res
]

parseLeaf["()"]:=clj[]
parseLeaf[expr_]:=Module[{head,rest,strc,sr},
    strc=StringCases[expr,{("("~~Shortest["hd["~~h__~~"]"]~~Whitespace~~r___~~")"):>{h,r},("("~~Shortest[h__]~~Whitespace~~r___~~")"):>{h,r}}];
    If[strc=={},
        sr=StringCases[expr,"("~~h__~~")":>h];
        Return[clj[sr[[1]]]]];
    {head,rest}=strc[[1]];
    rest=StringCases[rest,
            {n:("$"~~NumberString):>n,
            Shortest["\""~~s___~~"\""]:>str[ToString[s]],
            Shortest["clj[",s___,"]"]:>clj[s],
            Shortest["hd[",s___,"]"]:>hd[s],
            Shortest["[",s___,"]"]:>vec[s],
            Shortest["{",s___,"}"]:>dict[s],
            n:NumberString:>num[n],
            (n:(WordCharacter|"-"|"*"|"."|"#"|"/")..):>var[n]}
    ];
    clj[hd[head],rest]
]
```

**References:**

- I've checked out http://clojuratica.weebly.com/ exists, which helps you call mma from within clojure.

Comment: This question can be answered with the functional parsers part of [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/49053/34008) of the question ["CSS Selectors for Symbolic XML"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/49052/css-selectors-for-symbolic-xml).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This answer is based on the *Mathematica* functional parsers package [FunctionalParsers.m](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/FunctionalParsers.m) used and described in [these blog posts](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/category/functional-parsers/).

This command loads that package:

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/FunctionalParsers.m"]
```

### Using direct parser definitions (first answer)

Consider the EBNF:

```
<space> = { 'WhitespaceCharacter' } ;
<var> = { 'WordCharacter' } ;
<number> = { 'DigitCharacter' } ;
<atom> =  <var> | <number> ;
<vector> = '[' , <atom> , { <space> , <atom> } , ']' ;
<arg> =  <atom> | <vec> | <tree> ;  
<args-list> = <arg> , { <space> , <arg> } ; 
<head> = <var> ;
<tree> = '(' , <head> , [ <space> , <args-list> ] , ')' ;
```

Define the corresponding parsers:

```
pSPACE = ParsePredicate[StringMatchQ[#, WhitespaceCharacter ..] &];

pVAR = var[StringJoin[#]] &\[CircleDot]ParseMany1[
    ParsePredicate[
     StringMatchQ[#, 
       Except[{"(", ")", "[", "]", WhitespaceCharacter}] ..] &]];

pNUMBER = 
  num[ToExpression[StringJoin[#]]] &\[CircleDot]ParseMany1[
    ParsePredicate[StringMatchQ[#, DigitCharacter ..] &]];

pATOM = ParseSpaces[pNUMBER\[CirclePlus]pVAR];

pVECTOR = 
  vec @@ # &\[CircleDot]ParseShortest[
    ParseBracketed[ParseListOf[pATOM, pSPACE]]];

pARGSLIST = 
  ParseShortest[
   ParseListOf[
    ParseSpaces[pATOM\[CirclePlus]pVECTOR\[CirclePlus]pTREE], pSPACE]];

pHEAD = hd @@ # &\[CircleDot]pVAR;

ParseRecursiveDefinition[pTREE, 
  clj @@ Join[{#[[1]]}, #[[2]]] &\[CircleDot]ParseParenthesized[
    pHEAD\[CircleTimes]ParseOption[
      pSPACE \[RightTriangle] pARGSLIST]]];
```

Note that `pVAR` is defined for a larger set of strings than `<var>` in the EBNF. Here is a prettier view on that code:

[image]

`\[CirclePlus]`, `\[CircleTimes]`, and `\[CircleDot]` correspond to the parsers `ParseAlternativeComposition`, `ParseSequentialComposition`, and `ParseApply` respectively.  A triangle points to the parser the output of which is picked up in a sequential composition.

Parse the example in the question:

```
res = pTREE[Characters["(defn double-int [i] (* i 2))"]]

(* {{{}, clj[hd["defn"], {var["double-int"], vec[var["i"]], 
    clj[hd["*"], {var["i"], num[2]}]}]}} *)
```

and plot the result:

```
TreeForm[res[[1, 2]]]
```

[image]
Here are other parsing examples:

```
In[164]:= pTREE[Characters["(defn myfun [i j k] (list (* i 2) (+ j 5) (sq k)))"]]

Out[164]= {{{}, clj[hd["defn"], {var["myfun"], vec[var["i"], var["j"], var["k"]], 
    clj[hd["list"], {clj[hd["*"], {var["i"], num[2]}], 
      clj[hd["+"], {var["j"], num[5]}], clj[hd["sq"], {var["k"]}]}]}]}}

In[165]:= pTREE[Characters["(defn myfun [i j k] (list))"]]

Out[165]= {{{}, clj[hd["defn"], {var["myfun"], vec[var["i"], var["j"], var["k"]], 
    clj[hd["list"]]}]}}
```

### Using parser generation from EBNF (update)

Instead of defining the parsers for each of rule of the EBNF grammar we can use the [FunctionalParsers.m](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/FunctionalParsers.m) package to generate the parsers from the EBNF grammar.

```
ebnfCode = "
  <tree> = '(' &> <head>, [ <args-list> ] <& ')' <@ clj@@#& ;
  <head> = <var> <@ hd@@#& ;
  <args-list> = { <arg> } ; 
  <arg> = <atom> | <vector> | <tree>; 
  <atom> = <var>|<number>; 
  <var> = '_WordString' <@ var ;
  <number> = '_?NumberQ' <@ num ;
  <vector> = '[' &> { <atom> } <& ']' <@ vec@@#& ;
  ";
```

The strings "&>" and "<&" stand for "parse sequentially and pick right" and "parse sequentially and pick left" respectively. The string "<@" stands for "apply to the parsing result of #1 the modifier function #2".

This command generates the parsers:

```
GenerateParsersFromEBNF[ParseToEBNFTokens[ebnfCode]];
```

For each EBNF rule a separate parser is made. E.g. for `<vector> = ...` the parser `pVECTOR` is made.

The generated definition of the parser `pVAR` has to be extended in order to allow the symbols "-", "_", etc. to be in the variable names.

```
pVAR = var\[CircleDot]ParsePredicate[
    StringMatchQ[#, Except[{"(", ")", "[", "]"}] ..] &];
```

Let us define a dedicated tokenizer for the considered Clojure expressions:

```
ToClojureTokens = ParseToTokens[#, {"(", ")", "[", "]"}, {" ", "\n"}] &;
```

With the tokenizer we can make the following table of parsing results:

```
statements = {"[7  34  5 72]", "(ar [7  34  5 72])", "(m 3 (p 4 6))", 
   "(defn doubleint [i] (* i 2))", "(list (* i 2) (+ j 5) (sq k))", 
   "(defn myfun [i j k] (list (* i 2) (+ j 5) (sq k)))"};
ParsingTestTable[pTREE, statements, 
 "TokenizerFunction" -> ToClojureTokens, "Layout" -> "Vertical"]
```

[image]

Here are the tree forms of the parsed expressions in the table:

```
Map[TreeForm@*First@*Reverse@*First@*pTREE@*ToClojureTokens, statements]
```

[image]

### Other discussions

The functional parsers approach has been discussed also in answers of other MSE questions.

1. ["CSS Selectors for Symbolic XML"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/49053/34008) ;
2. ["General strategies to write big code in Mathematica?"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/110129/34008)

Comment: This is impressive. +1, of course.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin  Thanks! This question and my answer fit very well our recent discussion on DSLs.

Comment: @AntonAntonov how would you change your code to parse special clojure charaters like @, ~, `, and quote literals like '(1 2 3 4)?

Comment: @user5601 I think such a change is pretty easy. For example, we can add an EBNF rule `<literal> = \"'\" , <tree> ;`. Would you consider updating the question with the clojure expressions you have in mind? (Or make a new question...)

Answer (score 6):

I have a solution which is brittle only in that the Clojure expressions "(", ")" could mess up bracket detection and that I rely on strings like "<4>" to keep track of things. It's not very brittle once string handling is properly treated. Don't know if it's any better than yours, but it was fun to write and I think it's rather slick, modulo aforementioned fixable brittleness. Special mention to the use of a closure `varname` to count the leafs.

- `parse` just takes a depth-1 Clojure expression like `(head arg1 arg2 arg3)` and returns `"head"["arg1", "arg2", "arg3"]`.
- `prepare` replaces `[contents]` with `(List contents)` in the string.
- `splitTree` breaks out the expression into `{top-expression, {{label -> sub-expression, label -> sub-expression, …}}}`; see example below.

---

```
parse[expr_String?(StringFreeQ[StringTake[#, 2 ;; -2], "("] &)] := 
 (#[[1]] @@ Rest[#]) &@
  StringSplit[StringTake[expr, 2 ;; -2], " "]

varname[start_: 0] := 
 Module[{p = start}, (p++; "<" <> ToString[p] <> ">") &]

prepare[str_] := 
 (
  newvars = varname[];
  StringReplace[str, 
   Shortest["[" ~~ x__ ~~ "]"] :> "(List " <> x <> ")"];
 )

splitTree[str_] := 
 Reap@FixedPoint[
  StringReplace[#, 
   x : r__ ~~ int : Shortest["(" ~~ __ ~~ ")"] ~~ s__ :>
    (With[{var = newvars[]}, Sow[var -> int]; 
    r <> var <> s])] &, str]
```

Example usage:

```
prepare["(defn double-int [i] (* i (+ 3 4)))"]
```

outputs

```
"(defn double-int (List i) (* i (+ 3 4)))"
```

then

```
output = MapAt[parse, splitTree[%], {2, 1, All, 2}]
```

outputs

```
{"(defn double-int <3> <2>)",
 {{"<1>" -> "+"["3", "4"], 
   "<2>" -> "*"["i", "<1>"],
   "<3>" -> "List"["i"]}}}
```

then

```
parse[output[[1]]] //. output[[2, 1]]
```

outputs

```
"defn"["double-int", "List"["i"], "*"["i", "+"["3", "4"]]]
```