# Parse command line arguments

Tags: command-line, parsing, scripting

I have been trying to parse command line arguments. 
There are a couple of types of options.

```
1. Mandatory
2. Optional
3. Alternative
```

There are built-in/3rd party libraries for this purpose in many other languages.

I haven't found any built-in functions for this purpose in Wolfram Lang. Is there any good way to do it in Wolfram Lang?

[image]

**Update 2017-05-27**

There is a example of parsing command line arguments in Haskell.

**Example**

universalbuild (-p|--project name.xcodeproj) (-s|--scheme schemename) (-c|--configuration configurationname)

**Implementation in Haskell**

```
projectOption = strOption (long "project" <> short 'p' <> metavar "name.xcodeproj" <> help "Build the project name.xcodeproj." )
schemeOption = strOption (long "scheme" <> short 's' <> metavar "schemename"  <> help "Build the scheme specified by schemename." )
configuraitonOption = strOption (long "configuration" <> short 'c' <> metavar "configurationname" <> help "Use the build configuration specified by configurationname when building each target.")

options :: Parser UBOptions
options = UBOptions <$> projectOption <*> schemeOption <*> configuraitonOption
```

I think the implementation in Haskell is concise and expressive. I don't expect it can be done like this in Mathematica, at least I think it illustrates how DSL can simplify tasks.

Comment: It is not clear what are you asking: parsing arguments given to `wolframscript`, or [parsing of a particular DSL in WL](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/110129/34008).

Comment: @AntonAntonov parsing arguments given to wolframscript. I didn't realise that arguments are DSL. I think they are DSL indeed.

Comment: I would like to mention that my answer fits your Haskell implementation -- the parsers are generated from EBNF for convenience. You can see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/111321/34008) that uses both direct implementation with functional parsers and parsers generation from EBNF for Clojure expressions.

Comment: @AntonAntonov Thanks, I will try to understand how it works. :)

Comment: I updated my answer with implementation corresponding to the Haskell code you posted. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The DSL perspective

As it is discussed in the comments, the question can be seen as parsing of a particular DSL in WL.

### Direct implementation

This notebook screenshot image shows a direct implementation corresponding to the Haskell example in the question with the package ["FunctionalParsers.m"](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/FunctionalParsers.m):

[image]

Details on how to use the package ["FunctionalParsers.m"](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/FunctionalParsers.m) can be found here: ["Functional parsers for an integration requests language grammar.pdf"](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/Documentation/Functional%20parsers%20for%20an%20integration%20requests%20language%20grammar.pdf).

Some notes on the operators used:

- Shortcut operators:

  - "⊕" for `ParseAlternativeComposition`,
  - "⊗" for `ParseSequentialComposition`,
  - "⊙" for `ParseApply`.
- `ParseOption` is for optional parsing.
- I put function wrappers around the parsed results with `ParseApply`.

Here is the code:

```
pOptionValue = 
  ParsePredicate[
   StringMatchQ[#, 
     Except[{"-", "(", ")", "[", "]", WhitespaceCharacter}] ..] &];
pProgramName = Program\[CircleDot]pOptionValue;
pProjectOption = 
  Project\[CircleDot]((ParseSymbol["-p"]\[CirclePlus]ParseSymbol[
        "--project"])\[CircleTimes]pOptionValue);
pSchemeOption = 
  Scheme\[CircleDot]((ParseSymbol["-s"]\[CirclePlus]ParseSymbol[
        "--scheme"])\[CircleTimes]pOptionValue);
pConfigurationOption = 
  Configuration\[CircleDot]((ParseSymbol[
        "-c"]\[CirclePlus]ParseSymbol[
        "--configuration"])\[CircleTimes]pOptionValue);
pHelp = Help\[CircleDot](ParseSymbol["-h"]\[CirclePlus]ParseSymbol[
      "--help"]);
pOptions = 
  ParseMany[
   pProjectOption\[CirclePlus]pSchemeOption\[CirclePlus]\
pConfigurationOption\[CirclePlus]pHelp];
pCommand = 
  ParseShortest[
   Flatten\[CircleDot](pProgramName\[CircleTimes]ParseOption[pOptions])];
```

### Answer using parser generation from [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)

I am posting this part of the answer since the following command line DSL was easy to program with ["FunctionalParsers.m"](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/FunctionalParsers.m) (it took me 15-20 minutes) using EBNF specification and parsers generation.

First we program the command line DSL in [Extended Backus-Naur Form (EBNF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form):

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/FunctionalParsers.m"]

ebnfCommandLine = "
  <command-line> = <program> , [ <arg-list> ] ;
  <program> = '_WordString' <@ CLProgram ;
  <arg-list> = { <arg> } <@ CLArgumentList ;
  <arg> = <timeout-spec> | <source-spec> | <help> | <option-name> ,  <option-value> <@ CLArgument ;
  <option-name> = '_String' <@ CLOptionName ;
  <option-value> = '_String' <@ CLOptionValue ;
  <help> = '--help' | '-h' <@ CLHelp ;
  <timeout-spec> = ( '--timeout' | '-t' ) &> '_?NumberQ' <@ CLTimeoutSpec ;
  <source-spec> = ( '--source' | '-src' ) &> '_String' <@ CLSourceSpec ;
  ";
```

Note that in the EBNF string above I have used function wrappers for the parsing rules. Some of them can be skipped (e.g. `CLArgumentList`).

The following generates the parsers from the EBNF string:

```
GenerateParsersFromEBNF[ToTokens[ebnfCommandLine]];
LeafCount[res]
(* 258 *)
```

Here we overwrite the parser for `<option-name>` in order to make it more specific. (Hard to do in the EBNF string.)

```
pOPTIONNAME = 
  ParseApply[CLOptionName, 
   ParsePredicate[
    StringMatchQ[#, ("-" | "--") ~~ (WordCharacter ..)] &]];
```

Here is a table of example command parsings:

```
commands = {"example",
   "example --help",
   "example1 --timeout 123",
   "example2 -t 34 -src ./MyFile.php",
   "exampleUknownOption --timeout 34 --source ./MyFile.php -out ./MyFile.PHP",
   "exampleFail1 --timeout 34 --source ./MyFile.php -;out ./MyFile.PHP",
   "exampleFail2 5 6 out xxx",
   "exampleMisSpell --timeout 34 --sourse ./MyFile.php"
   };
ParsingTestTable[ParseShortest[pCOMMANDLINE], commands, "Layout" -> "Vertical"]
```

[image]

For more details on programming DSLs see the blog post:
["Creating and programming domain specific languages"](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2016/03/22/creating-and-programming-dsls/).

Answer (score 4):

Command line arguments are stored in [`$CommandLine`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$CommandLine.html). Mine looks like this:

```
$CommandLine
(* {"/Applications/Mathematica 11.app/Contents/MacOS/WolframKernel", 
    "-wstp", "-mathlink", 
    "-linkprotocol", "SharedMemory", "-linkconnect", "-linkname", "cddhm_shm"} *)
```

You can parse these relatively easily with the usual functions such as `MemberQ`, `Position`, `Replace`, etc.  For example,

```
Replace[$CommandLine, {___, "-linkname", linkname_, ___} :> linkname]
(* "cddhm_shm" *)
```

Several of the standard arguments, such as `-noinit` or `-nopaclet` are in fact handled in Wolfram Language code. You can find references to these if you browse the `$InstallationDirectory`.

Many tools these days use `-` for single letter flags and `--` for multi-letter ones.  I do not think it is a good idea to use this convention with Mathematica because its multi-letter built-in options all use a single `-`.  It would not be possible to distinguish them from single-letter flags.