# Markdown parser in Mathematica

Tags: import, xml

Is there already a markdown to XML parser implemented in Mathematica? I wrote a one for my pelican rewrite, but realized I should have asked here first. Mine is almost certainly faulty in a few major ways (I just don't know them yet) and would much rather use some one else's if it exists.

Comment: I do not think Mathematica has a ton of support for Markdown in any capacity. Maybe someone knows something I do not though.

Comment: @user6014 I'm pretty sure there's no native implementation for anything. It would be nice, but also something of a blow given the amount of time I've sunk implementing this kind of thing. I was more wondering if the community had some gold-standard markdown parser.

Comment: Most of the discussions I have seen on MSE are about the other direction: [from Mathematica to Markdown](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=Mathematica+to+Markdown). You might find some useful ideas in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/49053/34008) of ["CSS Selectors for Symbolic XML"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/49052/34008).

Comment: @AntonAntonov the issue is less doing it myself as I've already done that. I more wanted to know if someone else has done it better. But that answer on CSS selectors is very useful. I will need to remember that one.

Comment: If you really need this (for using, not self-education), I would write a wrapper for some established library. Or why not just use the XHTML produced by the original application: https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/

Comment: @masterxilo If I were to do that I'd want to do it in at the C level through `LibraryLink`, rather than introduce the `ProcessLink` overhead. And at that point the Markdown spec is simple enough, why not implement it oneself? I think it's a) a manageable problem and b) more easily tweak-able if implemented in Mathematica. But if someone had already done the work to write a ``"MarkdownLink`"`` I'd go with that.

Answer (score 6):

To get the ball rolling, [here's my incomplete parser](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/master/Packages/MarkdownParsers.m).

And [here's a minimal markdown sample](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/master/Resources/Templates/PacletServer/content/pages/About.md).

---

[This](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.testing/mdtest.html) is what my markdown parser makes of it, used like so:

```
CloudExport[
 MarkdownToXML[
   Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/\
 master/Resources/Templates/PacletServer/content/pages/About.md",
    "Text"
    ],
  "StripMetaInformation" -> False
  ],
 "HTML",
 "user:b3m2a1.testing/mdtest.html",
 Permissions -> "Public"
 ]

CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.testing/mdtest.html"]
```

(Note that it will strip that meta-information header block by default, hence the `"StripMetaInformation"->False`)

Comment: Does not seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The package
["Markdown2WL"](https://github.com/dishmint/Markdown2WL)
attempts that, but unfortunately it is fairly incomplete.
Also, see [the corresponding Community post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2142852).

---

*(In general I like the idea of a Markdown-to-Mathematica converter written in Mathematica.)*