# How to convert a Markdown file into a Mathematica notebook

Tags: notebooks, conversion

How to convert a Markdown file (or text) into a Mathematica notebook?

For example, easy conversion of comprehensive MSE posts is desirable.

---

Possible approaches ordered according to their convenience:

1. [ ] Extensions of ["pandoc"](https://pandoc.org) and/or ["jupytext"](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/).
2. [ ] Web service that does that.
3. [ ] A Mathematica package that does the conversion.

   - (An inverse of ["M2MD"](https://github.com/kubaPod/M2MD).)
4. [X] A stand-alone implementation (in some programming language.)

---

This question is an *inverse* of ["How to export a Mathematica notebook into Markdown?"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84556/34008).

There is a similar question,
["Markdown parser in Mathematica"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/154634/34008)
that asks for something more specific -- the Markdown parser to be written in Mathematica.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a stand-alone Command Line Interface (CLI) app implemented in Raku : ["Markdown::Grammar"](https://raku.land/zef:antononcube/Markdown::Grammar).

See the video
["Markdown to Mathematica converter (CLI and StackExchange examples)"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=39ekokgnoqE)
for a (quick, 7.5 min) demo.

[image]

---

For a detailed description see the corresponding:

- [Blog post](https://rakuforprediction.wordpress.com/2022/09/24/markdowngrammar/)
- [Community notebook post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2625639)

*Warning:* Installation of Raku on macOS (using rakudo.org) might be not that easy. I advice using [`rakubrew`](https://rakubrew.org).

---

Here is another
[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Htmiu3ZI05w)
showing how to convert Jupyter notebooks into Mathematica/WL notebooks:

[image]